# Reversing the order printed by an array

Tags: java, arrays

How would I go about reversing the order from ascending to descending? I am a bit stumped because I cannot use array.reverse, etc because on our tests we won't be allowed to use java built-in methods. Which is a bummer, arrays.sort is amazing. But as of now, it does print in ASCENDING ORDER. I am relatively new to coding and this site so if my format is bad. I apologise.

```
public static int[] sort(int a, int b, int c) {
    int[] j = {a, b ,c};
    int i, k, temp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        for(k = i + 1; k < j.length; k++) {
            temp = 0;
            if(j[i] > j[k]) {
                temp = j[i];
                j[i] = j[k];
                j[k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString((sort(6,3,11))));
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply switch this line:

```
if(j[i] > j[k]) {
```

to this:

```
if(j[i] < j[k]) {
```

This is because in the existing code, you are swapping the elements if the first one is larger (thus moving the larger one to later in the list).

When you use the second code snippet, it swaps the elements if the first one is smaller, thus moving the smaller one to later in the list.

Comment: Wow... ahaha... Thank you so much ! That is really useful to know and I feel bad for not even realizing that!

Comment: I know I have 3 variables, but does my for loop work if i had more than 3? or would I need to add extra variables like i and k? say I had 5,3,7,1,11.

Comment: Was smart enough to experiment myself. Removed the parameters and just set the j array to have 5 variables. Kept the for statements the same. Still worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @TylerR If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 streams to simplify this function.  Add a parameter to your sort function, and it becomes easy:

```
private static int[] sort(int a, int b, int c, boolean ascending) {
    Comparator<? super Integer> comparator = (ascending) ? Integer::compareTo : Comparator.reverseOrder();
    return Stream.of(a, b, c).sorted(comparator).mapToInt(t -> t).toArray();
}
```

Comment: not gonna lie.. a lot of that is over my head at this point in my coding career but I appreciate the simplified and I will study it and break it down